How to find the domain of the marginal pdf of $X$?
$f(x,y): 0<x<2-y, 0<y<1$
In this problem, how can I find the domain of the marginal pdf of $X$?
I was wondering the domain would be $(0,2)$ but I got a negative variance of $X$ with it.
Should I choose $(0,1)$? Or some else?

For the simultaneous inequalities $0 < x < 2-y$ and $0 < y < 1$, clearly if $y$ is a small number near $0$, then $x$ will range from $0$ to a number that is almost $2$.  So the marginal density of $X$ should have support on $(0,2)$, as you initially stated.  Since you haven't furnished your variance calculation nor your expression for the marginal density of $X$, I can't say why you got a negative value.  You would want to calculate
$$f_X(x) = \int_{y=0}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy$$ for $x \le 1$, but be careful:  when $x > 1$, the interval of integration needs to be $0 < y < 2-x$, because $2-x < 1$ when $x > 1$, and $y$ cannot be larger than $2-x$.

I see. I tried to calculate $f_(x)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y} (x,y)dy$ for every 0<x<2 and I think that is why I got a negative value. Thank you for your help.
